# Why is Google chrome on OSX resizing the app when autohidden apple menu bar is shown instead of overlapping it?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am on mac os 10.12.6 and I keep my Apple menu bar on auto hide. When an app is in fullscreen mode and I move my mouse towards the top of the screen causing the Apple menu bar to display, it overlaps the current app for the duration that it is visible. This used to be the case for Google Chrome also.

However, with latest update of Google chrome (69.0.3497.100), when the menu bar is visible, it bounces down chrome's tab bar triggering a resize of the chrome app. Because of this behaviour, when I move the mouse to the top of the screen to try click on a tab, I inadvertantly end up displaying the Apple menu bar and this causes Chrome to resize and the tab bar to move down. This is a real pain.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour and go back to the older overlap behaviour?

Comment: Same here. It started to happen when I did update of Chrome to 69

Comment: Is there any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I've opened an issue for a similar issue (manually resized to full screen, not full screen mode) that causes the browser to resize when using cmd-tab with an auto-hidden menu bar: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1070075

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if MacOS had a hotkey to manually turn the menu bar on/off.

The only decent workaround I've seen is setting a new Chrome `.plist` value.
This completely hides the dock and menu bars while you're using Chrome, so this would really just be a viable solution if you were giving a presentation/recording.

> Applications -> Chrome -> Right-click 'Show Package Contents' -> Contents -> info.plist -> Information Property List

Then select

```
Create key = 'Application UI Presentation Mode' and Value = 3
```